# Ways to set exposure on webcams reliably?

Tags: webcam

I'm working on a project where I use a webcam to continuously take pictures at varying exposure values (to make a stream of HDR images). I've been using a Logitech C310 camera and I've been setting the exposure value by sending the following to the command line:

```
"v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=exposure_absolute=%d --device=/dev/video1",exposureValue
```

This works pretty well when I set it to one exposure for a long time, then another, but when I try taking 3 frames in a row, the exposure doesn't change by much for each frame.

The other issue with my camera is that at its maximum exposure value of 10000 (whatever units this is I don't know), the frames aren't as exposed as I'd like them to be.

1) Is there some fundamental issue with constantly changing the exposure value that would stop it from working consistently on most webcams?

2) Are there webcams that anyone could recommend that are better suited for taking high-exposure shots?

Comment: Hi, I have the  task. but I am using opencv. but I did not find any solution to get different exposure images. Can you please share you code using v4l API. thanks

Answer (score 4):

The value ranges for `exposure_absolute` seems to be camera and driver specific. Most cameras mean the exposure time by this. Many cameras also provide the `gain` parameter, which controls the electrical amplification like the ISO setting on a digital camera. Go over to raising `gain` if `exposure_absolute` is already maxed out.

Both of them can be used in combination for exposure control, but there is no need for the existence of each of them on an abitrary camera. Some cameras provide both or only one of them or provide but ignore them as they only provide the `auto` mode.

So the most compatible way would be to check if there is a manual mode, set it and check if it is accepted, apply `exposure_absolute` and check if it is accepted, try `gain` otherwise or if `exposure_absolute` is already maxed out.

When recording video, there is another caveat, as large `exposure_absolute` values raise the exposure time beyond the frame interval and thus dropping the frame rate. That should be tested either to determine the point when `gain` should be used to keep a constant frame rate.

Also be aware that some v4l2 tools try to select the pixel format or resolution on their own, ignoring the `v4l2-ctl` selected ones, and some rare cameras tend to reset other parameters on this occassion.